# Firebase function reload for auth currentUser, doesn't refresh in vue component

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using the function reload for update the profile url, I have a computed property but this does not reflect the changes

Computed property

```
computed: {
    photoUrl: function() {
      return firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL;
    },
  }
```

Function

```
onFileChanged: async function(e) {
      this.image = e.target.files[0];
      if (this.image) {
        try {
          this.loading = true;
          const url = await saveImage(this.image, this.uploadProgress);
          await auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
            photoURL: url
          });
          await auth.currentUser.reload();
        } catch (error) {
          this.setTexto("Ocurrió un error al actualizar tu foto de perfil.");
          this.setColor("error");
          this.setVisible(true);
          console.error(error);
        } finally {
          this.progreso = 0;
          this.loading = false;
        }
      }
    }
```

I´m using firebase cloud storage upload file as a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative would be to have a simple property in the `data` object and update it in your function, as follows:

```
data: {
  //....
  photoUrl: null,
  //....
}

//...
onFileChanged: async function(e) {
      this.image = e.target.files[0];
      if (this.image) {
        try {
          this.loading = true;
          const url = await saveImage(this.image, this.uploadProgress);
          this.photoUrl = url;  // <-------
          await auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
            photoURL: url
          });
          await auth.currentUser.reload();
        } catch (error) {
          //...
        } finally {
          //...
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This solution sounds great but In case that I use this data in another component, I use then vue's store?

Comment: Yes you can use a Vuex store. You would then commit a mutation to update the `photoUrl` property in the Store state (instead of doing `this.photoUrl = url;`).